# According to Biblical Unitarians, are there Spirit-filled Christians in other denominations?

Tags: pneumatology, spirituality, biblical-unitarian, spiritual-growth

Not much to add to the title. Can Spirit-filled Christians be found in other denominations, according to Biblical Unitarians?

---

Related:

- [According to Trinitarians, can non-Trinitarians experience regeneration, sanctification and a Spirit-led life despite not believing in the Trinity?](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/q/86632/50422)
- [According to LDS, do all non-LDS Christians lack the Gift of the Holy Ghost, and if so, how does this lack manifest itself in the lives of non-LDS?](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/q/84049/50422)

Comment: I've never heard a Unitarian claim Non-Unitarians can't be Spirit-filled, but getting sources for this might be tricky ...

Comment: Most Biblical Unitarians probably believe Non-Unitarians make a conceptual error in their Christology (for certain), and are engaging in some form of small-i idolatry in treating Jesus as God instead of God's representative, icon, begotten Son, and King given all authority at the right hand of God. However, I haven't seen them making the same mistake made by the framers of the Athanasian or Nicene Creeds, in trying to claim salvation requires Unitarian beliefs contra, say, Trinitarian ones. But I'm sure those kinds of Biblical Unitarians exist.